# How to set font face in vanilla-extract/CSS

Tags: css, typescript

I have a simple quick question on how do one import a fontFace in vanilla-extract/css? I have read the documentation but I have not been able to workout thing. as per the documentation this is what should be the code

```
import { fontFace, style } from '@vanilla-extract/css';

const myFont = fontFace({
  src: 'local("Comic Sans MS")'
});

export const text = style({
  fontFamily: myFont
});
```

To be clear I want to use another font called Jungle Fever Nf my question is how do I import this font in the `src:'local("Jungle Fever Nf")` I have tried installing the font in my local machine but its not getting applied so I figured it out maybe if I point the src to the actual downloaded font file or import it in the css it will work but the problem is that I don't know how to do this in vanilla-extract/css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `globalFontFace` :

@/styles/fonts.css.ts

```
const contentFont = "Outfit";

globalFontFace(contentFont, {
    src: "url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/outfit/v6/QGYvz_MVcBeNP4NJtEtqUYLknw.woff2) format('woff2')",
    fontWeight: 100,
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontDisplay: 'swap'
});

export const fontText = style({
    fontFamily: contentFont,
});
```

Then, in your component :

```
import * as fontCss from "@/styles/fonts.css";

const MainTitle = () => {
    return <>
        <h1 className={fontCss.fontTitle}>Le Jo'</h1>
    </>
}

export default MainTitle;
```

Comment: Where did you get the font source?

Comment: For example, go to https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap

And you can see `src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');`

But, idk if this url changes or not